# Using template classes to create my own vector.size and vector.capacity functions?

Tags: c++, function, templates, vector, call

file.h:

```
template<class T>
T findSize(T &var){
    int *i = 0; //Pointer so that it retains its value after loop finishes.
    while(var.empty() != true){
        i++;
        var.pop_back();
    }
    cout << i << endl;

    return i;
}

template<class T>
T findCapacity(T &var){
    //How would I find the capacity?
    //This is the reason for the template, the capacity must increment by 10.
    //e.g. 10 elements = 20 capacity, 20 capacity, 30 capacity.
    //opposed to 1, 2, 4, 8...

    return something;
}
```

How I call the function from main.cpp:

```
    int temp;
    for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++){
        cin >> temp; //accepts number inputs from user (50 of them)
        vect.push_back(temp);

        cout << "Size: " << findSize(vect) << " Capacity: " << findCapacity(vect) << endl;
}
```

HUGE errors are obtained by: (UNSOLVED)

```
findSize(vect)
```

and

```
findCapacity(vect)
```

What is incorrect about my template/call above? ^^^

Also what would be the correct algorithm for finding the capacity?

As suggested, the unedited error:
http://pastebin.com/Qw1GPdkM

Comment: You're not specifying the type with a "<>"

Comment: Hm, your emptying a container so you can find its size? oO And *"int *i = 0; //Pointer so that it retains its value after loop finishes."* No, no, no. I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve with that, but that will **not** work.

Comment: A correct way for finding out the capacity would be to let the container mantain it and have a method to query it. The same with size.

Comment: If you ask about compilation errors, please always include *all* of them, *unedited* in the question. My guess is that it might have something to do with returning a pointer to `int` as `T`.

Comment: You wrote `findSize` to take a parameter. But you don't pass it any.

Comment: Also, if you want to find the size of a vector, you should not remove elements while doing the counting! Yes you will get the size, but doing that will also remove all elements!

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, Is there a way I could count the size without poping the vector?

Comment: you haven't written any template classes, you've written two template functions.  Both require arguments but you pass no arguments to either.  You're also calling them from object instances  as though they are members of a class - are they?

Comment: Store the size in the class, as well as the capacity.

Comment: @AliAlamiri, I tried to define the type, e.g. getSize<int>(vect); But that doesn't resolve the issue. By passing vect which is a vector<int> it should already know?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, How would I store the size without deleting the elements in my vector to count them? Or do you suggets I copy the vector into a second vector, then count one of them, deleting it in the process?

Comment: @KresimirBukovac how about adding something like `size_t mysize;` to your `var` type and maintain the count as a class invariant? That's the obvious approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual approach to keeping track of the size and capacity is to have member variables in the class.

Take for example this simple `int` vector class:

```
class int_vector
{
public:
    // Some public functions

private:
    size_t size;      // The current size
    size_t capacity;  // The current capacity
    int*   data;      // The actual "vector" data
};
```

Whenever you add a value to the above vector, you increase `size`, and decrease it when removing an item. The same with capacity as you allocate and reallocate the data.

---

As for some of your errors. The current `getSize` function should return the size (i.e. your counter) and not the template type. Think about if you store a structure in the vector, why would you want to return that structure type when getting the size? So changing that to e.g. `int` is a good start. Another good thing is to not use a pointer for the counter, plain `int` should be used (especially since increasing a pointer will increase it by the size of the underlying type, so for an `int` pointer it will increase by 4 (`int` is 32 bits, 4 bytes)).

Comment: Of course, Thanks.
That is what I was planning on doing if obtaining the size was not possible when all the elements have been stored in the vector already.

Comment: I have changed that function.
It now has size_t size;
In the while loop, I make size = i;
So, size is being returned.